# asp .net core 3.1 identity server

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I have a project that needs to be updated at .net core 3.1. The problem is that i don't know how to use this new feature from 3.1. I have my Identity Server Settings in appsettings.development.json, like this:

```js
"IdentityServerSettings": {
    "TokenUrl": "https://esample/token",
    "ClientId": "xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
    "ClientSecret": "yyyyy-yyyyy-yyyyy-yyyyy-yyyyyyyyy",
    "GrantType": "credentials",
    "Scope": "scope"
 }
```

Here is the Startup.cs:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var identityServerSettingsSection = this.Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServerSettings");
    services.AddIdentityServer()
    // here i need to app those properties from json
}
```

Here is how i read them from json file

```cs
identityServerSettingsSection.GetValue<string>("ClientId")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you mean something like this             var identityServerSettingsSection = this.Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServerSettings");

            services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.IssuerUri = identityServerSettingsSection.GetValue<string>("TokenUrl");
            });?

Comment: yes, something like that, but i want to add all the properties

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the different attributes of the section IdentityServerSettings you can do it like this, suppose you want to read ClientId.

this.Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServerSettings").GetSection("ClientId");

Or if you want to read all the attributes you can use the option pattern.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: but how i add the in services.AddIdentityServer?

Answer (score 0):

you can add identityserver like this

```
services.AddIdentityServer(Configuration);
```

which Configuration is IConfiguration. and for appsetting.json follow this [IdentityServer Options](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/identityServerOptions.html)